# F# async workflow / tasks combined with free monad

Tags: asynchronous, f#, async-await, free-monad, computation-expression

I'm trying to build pipeline for message handling using free monad pattern, my code looks like that:

```
module PipeMonad =
type PipeInstruction<'msgIn, 'msgOut, 'a> =
    | HandleAsync of 'msgIn * (Async<'msgOut> -> 'a)
    | SendOutAsync of 'msgOut * (Async -> 'a)

let private mapInstruction f = function
    | HandleAsync (x, next) -> HandleAsync (x, next >> f)
    | SendOutAsync (x, next) -> SendOutAsync (x, next >> f)

type PipeProgram<'msgIn, 'msgOut, 'a> =
    | Act of PipeInstruction<'msgIn, 'msgOut, PipeProgram<'msgIn, 'msgOut, 'a>>
    | Stop of 'a

let rec bind f = function
    | Act x -> x |> mapInstruction (bind f) |> Act
    | Stop x -> f x

type PipeBuilder() =
    member __.Bind (x, f) = bind f x
    member __.Return x = Stop x
    member __.Zero () = Stop ()
    member __.ReturnFrom x = x

let pipe = PipeBuilder()
let handleAsync msgIn = Act (HandleAsync (msgIn, Stop))
let sendOutAsync msgOut = Act (SendOutAsync (msgOut, Stop))
```

which I wrote according to [this article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-turtle-2/#way13)

However it's important to me to have those methods asynchronous (`Task` preferably, but `Async` is acceptable), but when I created a builder for my `pipeline`, I can't figure out how to use it - how can I await a `Task<'msgOut>` or `Async<'msgOut>` so I can send it out and await this "send" task?

Now I have this piece of code:

```
let pipeline log msgIn =
    pipe {
        let! msgOut = handleAsync msgIn
        let result = async {
            let! msgOut = msgOut
            log msgOut
            return sendOutAsync msgOut
        }
        return result
    }
```

which returns `PipeProgram<'b, 'a, Async<PipeProgram<'c, 'a, Async>>>`

Comment: Can you share complete code that you wrote so far (e.g. the `pipe` computation builder), so that we can try running this?

Comment: @TomasPetricek done

Comment: IMO, the whole point of the free monad is that you don't expose effects like Async, so I don't think they should be used in the PipeInstruction type. The interpreter is where the effects get added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my understanding, the whole point of the free monad is that you don't expose effects like Async, so I don't think they should be used in the PipeInstruction type. The interpreter is where the effects get added.

Also, the Free Monad really only makes sense in Haskell, where all you need to do is define a functor, and then you get the rest of the implementation automatically. In F# you have to write the rest of the code as well, so there is not much benefit to using Free over a more traditional interpreter pattern.
That TurtleProgram code you linked to was just an experiment -- I would not recommend using Free for real code at all.

Finally, if you already know the effects you are going to use, and you are not going to have more than one interpretation, then using this approach doesn't make sense.  It only makes sense when the benefits outweigh the complexity.

Anyway, if you did want to write an interpreter version (rather than Free) this is how I would do it:

First, define the instructions *without any effects*.

```
/// The abstract instruction set
module PipeProgram =

    type PipeInstruction<'msgIn, 'msgOut,'state> =
        | Handle of 'msgIn * ('msgOut -> PipeInstruction<'msgIn, 'msgOut,'state>)
        | SendOut of 'msgOut * (unit -> PipeInstruction<'msgIn, 'msgOut,'state>)
        | Stop of 'state
```

Then you can write a computation expression for it:

```
/// A computation expression for a PipeProgram
module PipeProgramCE =
    open PipeProgram

    let rec bind f instruction =
        match instruction with
        | Handle (x,next) ->  Handle (x, (next >> bind f))
        | SendOut (x, next) -> SendOut (x, (next >> bind f))
        | Stop x -> f x

    type PipeBuilder() =
        member __.Bind (x, f) = bind f x
        member __.Return x = Stop x
        member __.Zero () = Stop ()
        member __.ReturnFrom x = x

let pipe = PipeProgramCE.PipeBuilder()
```

And then you can start writing your computation expressions. This will help flush out the design before you start on the interpreter.

```
// helper functions for CE
let stop x = PipeProgram.Stop x
let handle x = PipeProgram.Handle (x,stop)
let sendOut x  = PipeProgram.SendOut (x, stop)

let exampleProgram : PipeProgram.PipeInstruction<string,string,string> = pipe {
    let! msgOut1 = handle "In1"
    do! sendOut msgOut1
    let! msgOut2 = handle "In2"
    do! sendOut msgOut2
    return msgOut2
    }
```

Once you have described the the instructions, you can then write the interpreters. And as I said, if you are not writing multiple interpreters, then perhaps you don't need to do this at all.

Here's an interpreter for a non-async version (the "Id monad", as it were):

```
module PipeInterpreterSync =
    open PipeProgram

    let handle msgIn =
        printfn "In: %A"  msgIn
        let msgOut = System.Console.ReadLine()
        msgOut

    let sendOut msgOut =
        printfn "Out: %A"  msgOut
        ()

    let rec interpret instruction =
        match instruction with
        | Handle (x, next) ->
            let result = handle x
            result |> next |> interpret
        | SendOut (x, next) ->
            let result = sendOut x
            result |> next |> interpret
        | Stop x ->
            x
```

and here's the async version:

```
module PipeInterpreterAsync =
    open PipeProgram

    /// Implementation of "handle" uses async/IO
    let handleAsync msgIn = async {
        printfn "In: %A"  msgIn
        let msgOut = System.Console.ReadLine()
        return msgOut
        }

    /// Implementation of "sendOut" uses async/IO
    let sendOutAsync msgOut = async {
        printfn "Out: %A"  msgOut
        return ()
        }

    let rec interpret instruction =
        match instruction with
        | Handle (x, next) -> async {
            let! result = handleAsync x
            return! result |> next |> interpret
            }
        | SendOut (x, next) -> async {
            do! sendOutAsync x
            return! () |> next |> interpret
            }
        | Stop x -> x
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. Since I'm new to functional patterns, it was really helpful for me to organize my thoughts and improve my understanding

Comment: Grundoon, when you say you recommend not using Free in real code, does that mean you don't have a problem with the traditional interpreter pattern?

Comment: Yes, using an interpreter is fine if the situation calls for it. Using Free as extra level of abstraction doesn't make sense in F#, imo.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I think that using free monads in F# is very close to being an anti-pattern. It is a very abstract construction that does not fit all that great with idiomatic F# style - but that is a matter of preference and if you (and your team) finds this way of writing code readable and easy to understand, then you can certainly go in this direction.

Out of curiosity, I spent a bit of time playing with your example - although I have not quite figured out how to fix your example completely, I hope the following might help to steer you in the right direction. The summary is that I think you will need to integrate `Async` into your `PipeProgram` so that the pipe program is inherently asynchronous:

```
type PipeInstruction<'msgIn, 'msgOut, 'a> =
    | HandleAsync of 'msgIn * (Async<'msgOut> -> 'a)
    | SendOutAsync of 'msgOut * (Async<unit> -> 'a)
    | Continue of 'a 

type PipeProgram<'msgIn, 'msgOut, 'a> =
    | Act of Async<PipeInstruction<'msgIn, 'msgOut, PipeProgram<'msgIn, 'msgOut, 'a>>>
    | Stop of Async<'a>
```

Note that I had to add `Continue` to make my functions type-check, but I think that's probably a wrong hack and you might need to remote that. With these definitions, you can then do:

```
let private mapInstruction f = function
    | HandleAsync (x, next) -> HandleAsync (x, next >> f)
    | SendOutAsync (x, next) -> SendOutAsync (x, next >> f)
    | Continue v -> Continue v

let rec bind (f:'a -> PipeProgram<_, _, _>) = function
    | Act x -> 
        let w = async { 
          let! x = x 
          return mapInstruction (bind f) x }
        Act w
    | Stop x -> 
        let w = async {
          let! x = x
          let pg = f x
          return Continue pg
        }
        Act w

type PipeBuilder() =
    member __.Bind (x, f) = bind f x
    member __.Return x = Stop x
    member __.Zero () = Stop (async.Return())
    member __.ReturnFrom x = x

let pipe = PipeBuilder()
let handleAsync msgIn = Act (async.Return(HandleAsync (msgIn, Stop)))
let sendOutAsync msgOut = Act (async.Return(SendOutAsync (msgOut, Stop)))

let pipeline log msgIn =
    pipe {
        let! msgOut = handleAsync msgIn
        log msgOut
        return! sendOutAsync msgOut
    }

pipeline ignore 0
```

This now gives you just plain `PipeProgram<int, unit, unit>` which you should be able to evaluate by having a recursive asynchronous functions that acts on the commands.